# Can we return multiple values using return statement in C?If not why did the code below compiled successfully?

Tags: c, return-value, return-type

Why and how did the program give the output?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sum(int a ,int b , int c ){
    return a , b ,c;
}
int main() {
    int a=10, b=100 , c=1000 ;
    int x = sum(a , b ,c);
    printf("%d %d %d" ,x);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output : 1000 1000 100

Comment: C and C++ are different languages, please don't tag C++ for C questions.

Answer (score 6):

Wow.  This is a spectacularly misleading result.

No, you can not return multiple values like this in C.  A function can have at most one single return value.  You can't use a comma to return multiple values like this.

But, if you can't do it, then why did it seem to almost work?  That's a rather complicated question, that it probably won't be possible to completely answer here.

Your program has two, completely unrelated problems.  The first problem, which isn't too serious, is the line

```
return a, b, c;
```

at the end of function `sum`.  In English, this line basically says, "Take the value `a` and throw it away, then take the value `b` and throw it away, then take the value `c` and have it be the actual return value."  (See [What does the comma operator do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do) for more about this comma operator.)

And then the second, much more serious problem is the line

```
printf("%d %d %d", x);
```

in `main`.  Your compiler should have warned you about this problem; mine says `warning: more '%' conversions than data arguments`.  You're telling `printf`, "I'm going to give you three `int` values to print".  But you lied, because you're then giving it just one `int` value, `x`.  So `printf` is blindly reaching for the other two values you promised, and getting... what?

By a reasonably incredible coincidence, when `printf` reaches out to fetch the values you *didn't* pass, it is somehow grabbing... one of the values that got thrown away by the poorly-written `return` statement back in function `sum`.  I'm not even sure how this happened, although when I tried your program on my computer, I got a similar result.

This may be too obvious to mention, but: this result is *not* guaranteed, it's not something to depend on, and it's not even something to learn from.  If you want to return multiple values from a function, there are other ways to do that, as this question's other answers have suggested.

Comment: About the "spectacular" result, it may be interesting to note that on my GCC with `-O0`, I get OP's result, while starting from `-O1` onward, I get garbage values. The key difference is that with `-O0`, GCC puts `a` and `b` on the stack, while starting from `-O1`, GCC simply translates `return a, b, c;` to `return c;`.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: no, you cannot return multiple values (at least, not as you did). Good news, you do have some ways to return multiple values from a function:

---

#### Method 1: use a `struct`

```c
typedef struct result {
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
} result_t;

result_t foo(int a, int b, int c) {
  return (result_t) { a + 1, b + 1, c + 1 };
}

int main(void) {
  result_t res = foo(1, 2, 3);
  printf("res.a is %d\n", res.a); // OUTPUT: res.a is 2
  return 0;
}
```

---

#### Method 2: use pointers as function arguments

```c
void some_calc(int input, int* output1, int* output2) {
  *output1 = input * 2;
  *output2 = input / 2;
}

int main(void) {
  int res1, res2;
  some_calc(50, &res1, &res2);
  printf("50 * 2 = %d and 50 / 2 = %d\n", res1, res2);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve with structs,

```
#include <stdio.h>

    struct Values
    {
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
    } values;
    
    
    struct Values sum(int a ,int b , int c ){
        return (struct Values){ a, b, c};
    }
    
    int main() {
        int a=10, b=100 , c=1000 ;
        struct Values x = sum(a , b ,c);
        printf("%d %d %d\n" ,x.a, x.b, x.c);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.  One more nitpick: You don't need the `typedef`, since you're not using `values`.

Answer (score 1):

This statement

```
printf("%d %d %d" ,x);
```

invokes undefined behavior because the number of arguments is less than the number of conversion specifiers.

In the return statement of the function

```
int sum(int a ,int b , int c ){
    return a , b ,c;
}
```

there is used the comma operator. The value of an expression with the comma operator is the value of the right-most operand. So in fact you have

```
int sum(int a ,int b , int c ){
    return c;
}
```

From the C Standard (6.5.17 Comma operator)

> 2 The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void
> expression; there is a sequence point between its evaluation and that
> of the right operand. Then the right operand is evaluated; the result
> has its type and value.

The function should look like

```
int sum(int a ,int b , int c ){
    return a + b + c;
}
```

of if to avoid a possible overflow then

```
long long int sum(int a ,int b , int c ){
    return ( long long int )a + b + c;
}
```

and in main you have tp write

```
printf("%lld\n", x );
```

If you want to return several objects from a function then a simplest way is declare a structure that contain the number of data members equal to the number of objects that you are going to return

For example

```
struct tuple
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

struct tuple f( int a, int b, int c );
```

Comment: I do like your answer, and I'm sorry if I sound pedantic, but just a little note: using `long long` to calculate `a + b + c` is not *always* going to avoid integer overflow, because `int` may be 64-bit, and `long long` may be 64-bit as well. There are stronger methods to detect overflow in arithmetic (like GCC's function `__builtin_sadd_overflow()`). Some of these may even be included in the next C standard. (But yes, *for most platforms* your method is correct).